# Discord bot - old posts with old nicknames

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py, tweets

I've prepared a discord bot that needs to post in name of other users, so I want it to change its nickname. I thought it went ok, but after I restart a client all posts changed to last nickname and no longer be recognizable by author.

Any ideas how to solve it?
Once I saw a discord bot (https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGQ3a.jpg) that posts tweets and changes the name depending on whom tweets it. So I guess it is possible.

Comment: Did that twitter bot share tweets in an embed? Because if so you could have the bot change its name depending on the occasion and embed it inside the message so it will stay even after you restart the client and all the names change

Comment: As on picture: https://imgur.com/a/eMsmIB3
All messages posted by one bot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you could do something like this

```
import discord
import random
import asyncio
from discord.ext.commands import Bot

client = Bot(command_prefix='!', case_insensitive=True)

@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def nick(ctx):
  await client.change_nickname(ctx.message.server.get_member("bot_id"),f"Name #{random.randrange(30)}")
  embed = discord.Embed()
  await asyncio.sleep(.01)
  embed.add_field(name = "Poster: ",value = ctx.message.server.get_member("bot_id").nick)
  await client.send_message(ctx.message.channel,embed = embed)
```

I'm not sure if you've tried this but the way that Twitter bot does it also resets its nickname to your client whenever you restart Discord

He also inserts the name of whoever is tweeting into the embed which lasts even after you restart the client.